# Is there native type-safe wrapping and unboxing for Object?

Tags: java, types

My inquiry is on wrapping, using the Object class as my wrapper.

My goal is to take the primitive int (or a wrapper of int) and unbox it from a generic Object.

The only problem is that I will be working with mixed types at runtime, so I am unable to generically type the return type of the method. T var1 != (T) var2

What I can do right now has excessive overhead because I cannot assume the Object wraps a value of type int, so I parse it.

```
Object int_wrapped_in_object = 1;

Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(int_wrapped_in_object));

//I could cast from Object to int with:
//(int) int_wrapped_in_object
//but this will always anticipate a classcastexception in case the value was wrapped with another type, like String
```

This works, but I would ideally like to skip a step of parsing and just unwrap box for the integer value.

Integer wrapper class does not support **valueOf(Object o)**, likely because Object does not implement the relative cast. It (Object) supports **toString()**. But not toInt(). It is very peculiar because Object indeed can wrap a primitive int. Why that is the case is above my level of knowledge, so I can only work with what I have. For all I know there may even be native support for unwrapping an Object as an int.

Please help me find a solution that involves using minimal parsing and introducing as few exceptions to get the primitive int value.

Comment: Please, provide code with the example when you need such a solution.

Comment: Why are you trying to "unbox" an int out of something that doesn't box an int?

Comment: "in case the value was wrapped with another type, like String" What on earth does that mean? If you have a string, then you don't have an integer value "wrapped", it's just a string.

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. You only use _ for SOME_CONSTANTS, not in "normal" names!

Comment: @leonbloy I will divulge that within the function, the return type of Object is wrapping 1 of x number of types. int, and String are 2 of the datatypes, and switched between because I am querying SQLite whose getType(int columnIndex) may vary-> not hard-coding the type for every statement executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Misconception on your end:

```
Object int_wrapped_in_object = 1;
```

The **type** of int_wrapped_in_object is **Integer**, not Object! The compiler already boxes for you!

In other words: there is **no** way that the java compiler would "box" an int into something that is "only" **Object**.

Thus a simple `int_wrapped_in_object instanceof Integer` is all you need to figure if that Object is actually an Integer. And then you can simply *cast*!

Comment: Thank you, my knowledge and appreciation of Object is greater thanks to you. I did not know about auto-boxing of the Object superclass into a more complex wrapper so I only assumed its signature was always only an Object.

Answer (score 2):

Your value gets wrapped to an `Integer` and then the view to it is reduced by casting it to `Object`.

You can later safely cast it back if you check the type with `instanceof`. Then you can unwrap it to `int` with the `Integer#intValue` method.

```
// Indirect conversion int -> Integer and then reduced view to Object
Object int_wrapped_in_object = 5;

if (int_wrapped_in_object instanceof Integer) {
    // Checked cast as the object indeed is an Integer but with reduced view
    Integer intAsInteger = (Integer) int_wrapped_in_object;

    // Retrieve the int value from the Integer
    // (you could also do an implicit unwrapping here) like
    // int value = intAsInteger;
    int value = intAsInteger.intValue();

    System.out.println("The value is: " + value);
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Value is no Integer but it should.");
}
```

Note that the line

```
Object int_wrapped_in_object = 5;
```

gets indirectly transformed to

```
Object int_wrapped_in_object = (Object) Integer.valueOf(5);
```

If you need to do such conversions often then just create an **utility method** which does that for you.

---

Note that the object itself stays `Integer` and gets not *converted* to an `Object`, that is not how casting works, only its view is reduced. You can check that with

```
System.out.println(int_wrapped_in_object.getClass())
```

It will print `class java.lang.Integer` and not `class java.lang.Object`. So the type of an object always stays the same, even after casting. You only reduce the view to it which has advantages like higher modularity.